# Problem connecting to Remote MySQL with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, connection-string

i'm using Visual Studio 2010 and when i bind a DataGridView with my remote mysql db it *works fine*.
but when i take the connection string from the wizard and try to use it with code i get: **"provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server"**

this is the connection string i try (i tried many variants):
**"Server=myserver.org;Database=my_db;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypwd;"**

any ideas?
thanks

here is the code:

`string connectionString = "Server = sql.server.org; Database = my_db; Uid = my_user; Pwd = mypwd;";`

```
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table", myConnection);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        DataRow myDataRow;

        // Create command builder. This line automatically generates the update commands for you, so you don't 
        // have to provide or create your own.
        SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);

        // Set the MissingSchemaAction property to AddWithKey because Fill will not cause primary
        // key & unique key information to be retrieved unless AddWithKey is specified.
        mySqlDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Table");
```

Comment: Could you show the non-working code?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: apparently **SqlConnection** is not made for MySQL

use: **MySqlConnection** instead

Answer (score 0):

```
           string connectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=***********;database=terra_incognita_online";
           MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection();
           sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
           sqlConnection.Open();
           Console.WriteLine("open");
           sqlConnection.Close();
           Console.WriteLine("close");
```